# Chunked communication which should stay in order

Tags: java, client-server, network-protocols

A server-client application talks over http/xml. The server sends xml files with a number or rather a chunk id. Sometimes the client receives a xml a higher chunk id than expected. So I need to queue it because the order is important. I use a `TreeMap<Integer, Document>` so I can add the xmls to the map till a xml is received with the expected chunk id. It's also possible that a xml is sent by the server but is newer received by client. The server doesn't know about this because of send-and-forget. So my question is how to deal with this problem? Should I refactor the architecture? It there a pattern for this?

**Example**

```
expected chunk id / real chunk id
      0                   0   eval
      1                   3   add to queue
      2                   4   add to queue
      3                   2   add to queue
      4                   1   add to queue
      5                   5   eval / eval queue
      6                   6   eval
      -                   7   no send to client
      7                   8   ?
      8                   9   ?
```

Comment: Is the underlying transport UDP? Typically HTTP uses TCP, which should preserve ordering. (Doesn't answer your question, just a musing on my part).

Comment: Also, as a small improvement, you could consider evaluating the queue at times other than when the expected chunk matches the received chunk. E.g. step 5 above, when you received `1`, gave you a complete run of `1`-`4`.

Comment: Yep your are right, but the problem is that the server doesn't send it in the right "logical" order. Wireshark already showed that. The other point is also a good one. I think I found a more or less good solution for it. https://github.com/alexvetter/Commodity/commit/25e8be184b69fbbb410bf51040a09ee464c79c91

Comment: @DuncanJones No one else answered to my question. I built a class `OrderedRunnableQueue` which does what I need and I considered your comment. [(class on github)](https://github.com/alexvetter/Commodity/blob/master/src/org/kaffeezusatz/commodity/collections/OrderedRunnableQueue.java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built a [OrderedRunnableQueue](https://github.com/alexvetter/Commodity/blob/master/src/org/kaffeezusatz/commodity/collections/OrderedRunnableQueue.java) where you can add `Runnable` with a number.